# Append div Above parent of specific div with changing order in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this may be possible but I'm not able to figure this one out... I need to inject a div into the parent of a nested element and have it appended before that elements parent... The trouble comes when I can't target the location by looking for the specific instance in the parent. Hopefully the code will clarify

I need to Use the id from the nested div

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="startFromHere"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

And insert a div above the main parents location in the list

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="theAppendedDiv"></div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="startFromHere"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

I can not target the 3rd element in the list because the div with the ID I need targeted will not stay in the 3rd position, it will change. So if its the 5th item or the 2nd item, I have to append a div before the parent of that specific nested div.

I also have no control over the html and have to inject this through js/jquery. It could be up to 10 levels deep, nested in spans/tables/divs ect... None of the parent elements are labeled, The only thing I can use to target anything is a nested elements ID.

Comment: So the injection always takes place at the second level of divs but the element with the ID may be at any depth? If so, can you select the root level? If not, how do you know where the root level is? If you have the root level and the ID, it should be simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parent()` method like following.

```js
$('#startFromHere').parent().parent().before('<div id="theAppendedDiv">The Appended Div<div>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="startFromHere">Start From Here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I love when there's a simple solution, Thanks did exactly  what I needed. Didn't think it would keep track of the position in the dom after backtracking multiple parents.

Answer (score -1):

This should work (**Updated code**):

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <p>I am paragraph</p>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

// Select the parent <div> element
  var parentDiv = $('.parent');

// Select all the <p> tags within the parent <div> and wrap them with <b> tags
  
  parentDiv.find('p').each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<b></b>');
  });
  
</script>
```